# How to compress python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

How can I compress a `for` loop in python?
I've read a lot of books in which they compress `for` loops but I never really understood how to do it. In my case, I am changing the form of a dictionary,
Here's the code:

```
    for i in attacks.items:
      attacks[i[0]] = i[1] + round(i[1]/level)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Those "lots of books" used the term "_compress_"?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'compressing' a loop.  You may be thinking of a list comprehension (or dictionary comprehension) which is a short-hand way of creating a new data structure based on a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a better way to iterate over the keys of a dict is to do exactly that:

```
for k in attacks:
    attacks[k] += round(attacks[k]/level)
```

Now I assume that "compressing" a loop means a "comprehension" for which there exist list, dictionary, set comprehensions etc. In your case you could write it as a dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {k:v+round(v/level) for k,v in attacks.items()}
```

Note, however, that this creates a new dictionary object, whereas your code (and my revised code) updates the existing dictionary inplace.